# Wordpress-seo-premium theme override

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin in wordpress - wordpress-seo-premium (Yoast SEO). I want to override the code in wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo-premium/css/main-sitemap.xsl. So that we remove the 'Generated by Yoast' information.

I have tried adding the exact same file in the path (with the removed content): wp-content/themes/[your-theme]/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo-premium/css/main-sitemap.xsl. However when I hard refresh the page, the content didn't update. Which tells me that I am adding the file in the wrong location.

Please could someone help me on this.